# TFS Labels or Branching for marking files for specific tasks

Tags: tfs, cvs, branching-and-merging, label

I'm newbie to TFS (2013). I used CVS in past, where we used to either create same Named Labels on multiple files or Branched labels to group files under one name, for specific tasks, like Marked with a build number, or Creating Patches/Hotfixes.

Now I'm looking for similar strategy in TFS.

**Question:** Is it possible to mark multiple folders/files with same Label?
Or
**Question:** Can we create a separate branch (with a particular name) upon multiple folders/Files?

Using any of above technique, I would be able to get multiple files, may be distributes among different folders, by specifying single Label/Name/Mark etc.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Even though *labels* exist in TFS, I recommend not to use these for branching. In stead use a specific *changeset* when branching a *codeline*.

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen. Yes, these would not be used instead of Branching. Now I'm planning to add Labeling technique at the end of every build.

Comment: What I mean is: Do your branching based on a TFS path and a changeset. I.e. $/ProjectX/Main changeset 12345. You can think of each changeset as a kind of label. These labels are created on each check-in, you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark folders with labels via: Team Explorer (in VS) -> right click on folder -> Advanced -> Apply Label
You can branch in a similar way, TE -> right click -> branching and merging.

A good place to start would be to read the ALM Rangers' pdf on [Branching Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/releases).

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it won't let me label folders with same label. For instance, if I Label one folder with lb1 and then later, in some other folders, I tried to label a subfolder with lb1, it will remove first one and apply it on later folders.